# Read hex characters and convert them to utf-8 using python 3

Tags: python, utf-8

I have a file data.txt containing this string:

```
M\xc3\xbchle\x0astra\xc3\x9fe
```

Now the file needs to be read and the hex code interpreted as utf-8.

So far this is my try:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import os
import sys

with open("data.txt") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        print( bytes(line, 'utf-8').decode("unicode_escape"))
```

The output converts the newline (\x0a), but does not work with multi-byte utf-8 characters:

```
MÃ¼hle
straÃe
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
line = line.decode('unicode_escape').encode('latin-1').decode('utf8')
```

Comment: Thanks, that's it. A small correction though: line = bytes(line, 'utf-8').decode('unicode_escape').encode('latin-1').decode('utf8')