# Read str from file contain hex bytes str character and decode?

Tags: python, python-3.x, decode

I have a file `example.log` which contains:

```
<POOR_IN200901UV xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ITSVersion="XML_1.0"
xsi:schemaLocation="urn:hl7-org:v3
../../Schemas/POOR_IN200901UV20.xsd">\n\t<!-- \xe6\xb6\x88\xe6\x81\xafID -
->\n\t<id extension="BS002"/>
```

I want to read the file and convert the str to `utf-8` encoding format and write to a new file. Currently my code below:

```py
with open("example_decoded.log", 'w') as f:
    for line in open("example.log", 'r', encoding='utf-8'):
        m = re.search("<POOR_IN200901UV", line)
        if m:
            line = line[m.start():-2]
            line_bytes = bytes(line, encoding='raw_unicode_escape')
            line_decoded = line_bytes.decode('utf-8')
            print(line_decoded)
            f.write(line_decoded)
        else:
            pass
```

But the `example_decoded.log`'s content:

```
<POOR_IN200901UV xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ITSVersion="XML_1.0" 
xsi:schemaLocation="urn:hl7-org:v3 
../../Schemas/POOR_IN200901UV20.xsd">\n\t<!-- \xe6\xb6\x88\xe6\x81\xafID -
->\n\t<id extension="BS002"
```

The `\xe6\xb6\x88\xe6\x81\xaf` part isn't being decoded, so I am wondering how to deal with this mix-type str decode issue?

Comment: **1st** specify `with open("example_decoded.log", 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:` and **2nd** try `line_decoded = line.encode( 'utf-8').decode( 'unicode-escape').encode( 'latin1').decode( 'utf-8')`

Comment: yes, I already found solution, did encode with `latin-1`, but i am confuse why this work, could you provide me with some background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer this: [Read hex characters and convert them to utf-8 using python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27493554/read-hex-characters-and-convert-them-to-utf-8-using-python-3)

the solution is:

```
with open("example_decoded.log", 'w') as f:
    for line in open("example.log", 'r', encoding='utf-8'):
    m = re.search("<POOR_IN200901UV", line)
    if m:
        line = line[m.start():-2]
        line_decoded = bytes(line, 'utf-8').decode('unicode_escape').encode('latin-1').decode('utf8')
        print(line_decoded)
        f.write(line_decoded)
    else:
        pass
```

although I don't understand why `encode('latin-1')`first,
can someone explain that?

Answer (score 0):

```
decodedVal = struct.unpack(">f", bytes.fromhex(encdoded_val))[0]
```

refer below link to add your endian and type instead of `">f"`

https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html

Answer (score 0):

```
import codecs

decode_hex = codecs.getdecoder("hex_codec")

string = decode_hex(string)[0]
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html

Comment: what i meant is to decode the entire string, not just hex part